# Adding python libraries to google datalab environment

Tags: anaconda, bokeh, google-cloud-datalab

I'm using [google datalab](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/) on google cloud platform. Worked great on the first try and I love how easy it is to now run a jupyter notebook server in the cloud (faster than starting up a localhost server). It's fantastic.

But now I want to install python libraries not included in the basic datalab environment (specifically I need the Bokeh plotting library).

So I opened a google cloud shell from the google cloud console where I manage this jupyter notebook instance, installed miniconda and then the bokeh library.  Everything ran without error (e.g. bokeh installs several dependencies along the way), but my jupyter notebook on datalab (which can import other libraries like numpy) still gives me a "no module named bokeh.plotting" error.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to install via `conda`, or only `pip` per the below answer? I'm looking for a `conda` solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025059/install-conda-package-from-google-datalab

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this inside a notebook:

```
%%bash
pip install bokeh
```

Comment: Or more generally, for multi-line commands   
    %%bash  
    # whatever command

Comment: Thanks that worked.  Note that as @Dinesh points out it is %%bash and the pip install command on a newline. As first answered it was rendered as a oneliner with %bash rather than %%bash

Comment: Yes, thanks, updated. I had a separate line but SO folded them.

Comment: So, just so that I can understand.. Is there a simple answer to why the conda installation from the cloud shell did not make the library available?  Are they different python environments, or something?

Comment: Datalab is running in a container in the VM so it is sandboxed from the rest of the VM.

Comment: Last question. This %%bash magic runs non-Interactive shell commands.  Is there a way to get an interactive shell for those times one needs interaction (e.g. conda installer that prompts y/n to continue)?

Comment: No interactive shell although you can use pipe, so maybe "echo 'y' | ..." will work